# Arch Linux: Should I keep the dhcpd service if I'm using connman?

Tags: arch-linux, dhcp, internet

Running `systemd-analyze blame` tells me that `dhcpd.service` is running.

I remember enabling this in order to get automatic Ethernet connection back when I was installing Arch.

Now I installed connman and using `connman.service`.

Should I disable dhcpd or is it still necessary for connman and wired connections? Checking the wiki for connman it says it handles wired just fine, without mentioning anything about dhcpcd so I assume not, but I would still like to know beforehand. :)

I also don't know if dhcpd is used for something else so I don't want to carelessly disable it.

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and recommend that you turn off `dhcpd.service`. The actual `dhcpd` program acts as a DHCP server. That is, if it hears some machine solicit a DHCP lease, it will give one out, according to the configuration in `/etc/dhcpd.conf`. A "lease" includes an Internet Protocol address, and usually things like default router, NTP server. The machine running `dhcpd` usually has a static configuration itself.

Client machines, laptops, etc, usually run `dhcpcd`, which gets a machine an IP address and other configuration information dynamically, like whenever they join a new wireless network. One letter in the program name means different functionality.

If a machine uses a network manager like `connman`, it's probably not in a position to give out IP addresses and default routes to other machines. Of course, exotic situations merit exotic configurations, so maybe you and some other people have a way to set this up that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :) Indeed I don't want dhcpcd giving out that kind of information. Thanks. :)

Comment: Yup. Internet works after a reboot. Gonna accept now. ;P